# Where do questions about documentation go?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

For example, I enjoyed this article by [Hackernoon](https://hackernoon.com/reactjs-component-lifecycle-methods-a-deep-dive-38275d9d13c0).

but I wanted to see the actual documentation for all the life cycle methods so I started [looking at the facebook-react docs here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html).

There is a discrepancy between Hackernoon and Facebook, in that Facebook lists 3 divisions of the lifecycle while Hackernoon lists 4.

Basically Facebook considers the initialization which is done in the constructor to be part of mounting.

The question is about correctness, is Hackernoon not correct or is this an acceptable "translation".  Where should this question go?

Comment: Both links are identical

Comment: updated the link mistake.

Answer (score 13):

*Should* it be a question?  I'm leaning towards "no" simply because the React documentation should be *the* authoritative source on concepts such as lifecycle.

It would likely be *better* as a question if there was a lifecycle problem that you were encountering; that is (and I'm *super* naive in React anymore), if somehow you had tests from examples in the official documentation that validated that initialization and mounting were separate, and they were failing in a specific version of React.  That would be a *better* situation to be in as it indicates that there could have been a change in behavior between versions, and that'd be something that someone who knows React could answer.

But given a choice between two sources for authoritative information on a lifecycle?  The official docs are the only option that make sense in any context.

Comment: Open source code trumps official documentation :-)

Comment: "React documentation should be the authoritative source on concepts such as lifecycle" Maybe, but if I google a question the first link I click on is the one that leads to stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Clint: ...which is not surprising given how dominant Stack Overflow is with search engines.  But that doesn't make Stack Overflow *authoritative*.

Answer (score 13):

The best place to ask about correctness of documentation, is in that documentation's issue tracker.

Such questions are mostly off-topic for Stack Overflow.
The problem with *"Is external site  correct or is external site  correct"*, is that X and Y can change or go offline at any moment, invalidating answers, or even the question itself.

Comment: Agreed. This is one of those "not _everything_ has to be on Stack Exchange, you know?" moments.

Comment: Heh. I asked such a question once on SO, basically the question the OP wants to ask, and nobody commented that it was off topic, and it didn't attract a single downvote! It was long ago though (in fact, it was my first question here) so the atmosphere was different.

Comment: @DaanHeskes: That has ___Nothing___ to do with the users being new, and ___everything___ with the quality of their questions. I see plenty of new users successfully posting questions on SO.

Answer (score 3):

Another good place to ask something like this would be the React chat on Stack Overflow. If anyone is around they may be able to help you with your issue.